# Can I start the conversation with messenger bot?

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger

My bot is running in perfect conditions when I use it trought funpage.
But what I want to know is if we can start the conversation with the user instead user with it.

For example: The user is on a page that his next interation is talk with my BOT. But i don´t want my clients start I want my bot starts.

At this case we can consider that user already authorized my app.

Answer (score 2):

Not if this is their first messenger interaction with you.

 
When you message a user, you're sending a message to a user id that is *page scoped.*

So unless they've previously messaged your page, there's no way for you to get their id

> The id must be an ID that was retrieved through the Messenger entry points or through the Messenger webhooks (e.g., a person may discover your business in Messenger and start a conversation from there.
>
> These IDs are page-scoped IDs (PSID). This means that the IDs are unique for a given page.
>
> If you have an existing Facebook Login integration, user IDs are app-scoped and will not work with the Messenger platform.

(see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference)